# WPF MVVM share properties between UI/background threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I can't find a simple example for how to achieve this anywhere online that I can understand. I also don't want to use MvvmLight.

My view contains a rectange with a fill colour that is bound to a SolidColorBrush property in my view model.

My model also has a SolidColorBrush property and an UpdateBrushColor method.

I want my view model to run a background thread that can call UpdateBrushColor in the model and then update its own SolidColorBrush to match the model brush color, this will then update the UI via data binding.

I use Dispatcher.Invoke in the background thead to update the UI but am still getting the exception: 'Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject'.

**View (just the control)**

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Rectangle Height="50"
              Width="50"
              Fill="{Binding Brush}">
  </Rectangle>
  <CheckBox></CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**Model**

```
class Model
{
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; } = Brushes.Black;

    public void UpdateBrushColor()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        byte r = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
        byte g = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
        byte b = (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255);
        Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
    }
}
```

**View model**

```
class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }

    private SolidColorBrush brush;
    public SolidColorBrush Brush
    {
        get { return brush; }
        set { SetProperty(ref brush, value); }
    }

    public Vm()
    {
        Model = new Model();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Model.UpdateBrushColor();

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {                        
                    Brush = Model.Brush;    // why can't access model from here?
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // Data Binding Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, creating a new Random instance in the UpdateBrushColor method makes no sense. It should be created once (as class member) and reused in the method.

Comment: That said, Model.Brush is created in the Task's thread (by the UpdateBrushColor call), so you can't assign it to Vm.Brush. All your code doesn't make much sense. Why wouldn't you just create a set of RGB values (or a Color value) in your model, and create a Brush from these values in your view model? You should also use a DispatcherTimer instead of a Task for any cyclic UI updates.

Comment: Yes I agree it doesn't make much sense in many ways. Apologies. I coded it quick to get a small generic example to explain my problem; a bad idea in hindsight. I wasn't aware thread affinity was a thing, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the Brush class in your model, because it is derived from DispatcherObject and hence has *thread affinity*. Instances created in a Task's thread can not be used in the UI thread.

You could use `Color`, which is a struct type without thread affinity.

Besides that, you could also use a simple DispatcherTimer for your cyclic updates:

```
public class Model
{
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    public Color Color { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateColor()
    {
        Color = Color.FromRgb(
            (byte)random.Next(256), (byte)random.Next(256), (byte)random.Next(256));
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Model Model { get; } = new Model();

    private Brush brush;
    public Brush Brush
    {
        get { return brush; }
        set
        {
            brush = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Brush)));
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)
        };

        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Model.UpdateColor();
            Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Model.Color);
        };

        timer.Start();
    }
}
```